# How can I patch the ceiling and rehang a shower curtain rod?

Tags: bathroom, repair, shower, ceiling

I have glass tiled walls in my bathroom, so opted to hang the shower curtain rod from the ceiling to protect the tiles. It looked great, until a house guest recently slipped, and grabbed the curtain for support. This pulled the teardrop bracket out of the ceiling, leaving a small tennis ball size hole. I would like to patch the ceiling, and then reattach the shower curtain rod bracket to ceiling.

[image: hole]

[image: what it should look like]

[image: the teardrop bracket]

Comment: This is exactly why it's best to attach these types of things to the framing members, and not only to the drywall/plaster. Is your house guest alright?

Comment: I use a shower curtain rod that stays in place with some horizontal tension.  Looks good and a much easier solution than proposed below (just have to patch).

Comment: That is an interesting way to hang the shower rod. I'm not sure if that design would ever be strong enough, even if it was attached to solid members in the ceiling. I'm also unsure about the rod and clamp you used to secure it. Depending on the metal, that may end up getting rusty over time. Most installers either use an adjustable shower curtain rod, or they use a tile bit to drill through the tile and permanently attach it to the wall.

Answer (score 3):

Realizing none of this is intended to support a person, or animal, or support anything over a person or animal.

Which answer would you like?

In order of suggested preference, and holding strength

- Open up the ceiling enough [24" x 8"] to get a piece of lumber screwed between 2 joists - then patch
- Open up the ceiling enough [10" x 6"] to get a piece of lumber laying between 2 joists - then patch
- Open up the ceiling enough [8" Circle] to get a fan support bracket between the joists then patch
- Open up the ceiling enough [6" x 6"] to get a large piece of drywall on top of ceiling, for 2 layer patch

Comment: Agree. Or, is there an attic above you can get into? Regardless, if you're going through this effort might as well attach a piece of wood blocking to screw it in to to be once and done.

Answer (score 0):

You can cut through ceiling a hole round 60cm x 60 cm (round 24 x 24 inches).A hole should be this big just to be on a safe side, because this is max distance between two substructure elements. If you find this elements in a smaller opening even better. At this point you have two choices: either you can fix curtain in ceiling substructure elements, or which is even better you can fix some screw (or some similar element which could be later connected with curtain carrier) in the attic. After that you should fix new piece of plasterboard properly and just repaint the ceiling.